# InvalidCastException occurs when try to Deserialization a JSON

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7

I try to deserialization a JSON like the following（Numbers like 93817 and 935812 are dynamically generated from a server. Can't be hard coded.）:

```
{   "status":"1",               
"list":{      
 "93817":{         "item_id":"93817",         
                   "url":"http://url.com",         
                   "title":"Page Title",         
                   "time_updated":"1245626956",                
                   "time_added":"1245626956",                
                   "tags":"comma,seperated,list",         
                    "state":"0"                       
          },      
 "935812":{         "item_id":"935812",         
                    "url":"http://google.com",        
                    "title":"Google",         
                    "time_updated":"1245626956",       
                    "time_added":"1245626956",      
                    "tags":"comma,seperated,list",         
                    "state":"1"                     
  }   }}
```

Here is the code for deserialization:

```
responseGetList =    e.Result.ToString(); //responseGetList is the JSON string

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream( Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(responseGetList));

DataContractJsonSerializer serializer =
    new DataContractJsonSerializer( typeof(List<ResponseItem>) );

ResponseItem li = (ResponseItem)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

And the following is the ResponseItem class:

```
namespace whatever
{
    [DataContract]
    public class ResponseItem
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "status")]
        string status;
        public string Status
        {
            get { return status; }
            set { status = value; }
        }
        [DataMember(Name = "list")]
        List<ListItem> list;
        private List<ListItem> List
        {
            get { return list; }
            set { list = value; }
        }
    }
    public class ListItem
    {
        [DataMember]
        List<Article> listArticle;
        public List<Article> ListArticle
        {
            get { return listArticle; }
            set { listArticle = value; }
        }
    }
}

public class Article
{
    [DataMember(Name = "item_id")]
    string item_id;
    public string Item_id
    {
        get { return item_id; }
        set { item_id = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "url")]
    string url;
    public string Url
    {
        get { return url; }
        set { url = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "title")]
    string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "time_updated")]
    string time_updated;
    public string Time_updated
    {
        get { return time_updated; }
        set { time_updated = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "time_added")]
    string time_added;
    public string Time_added
    {
        get { return time_added; }
        set { time_added = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "tags")]
    string tags;
    public string Tags
    {
        get { return tags; }
        set { tags = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "state")]
    string state;
    public string State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set { state = value; }
    }
}
```

I get InvalidCastException on 1`ataContractJsonSerializer serializer =
new DataContractJsonSerializer( typeof(List<ResponseItem>) );`, I think it is a JSON-Object mapping problem. Can any one help me?

Comment: That JSON doesn't look valid-- JSONLint doesn't think so, either.

Comment: Edited and it works now on JSONLint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by reading the source code of RIL# (http://rilsharp.codeplex.com/).
The problem is mainly mapping issue. Using **Dictionary** is the key resolution:

```
[DataContract]
public class ResponseItem
{
    [DataMember(Name = "status")]
    public ListStatus Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "since")]
    public double Since { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "list")]
    public Dictionary<string, RilListItem> items { get; set; }

    public DateTime SinceDate
    {
        get
        {
            return UnixTime.ToDateTime(Since);
        }
    }
```

Then using Json.net to deserialize the JSON:

```
  ResponseItem ri = new ResponseItem();
  ri = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseItem>(responseGetList);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using NewtonSoft's LINQ to Json, it's a way cleaner method to de/serialize json strings

```
ClassName class= new ClassName();
objectname = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassName>(responseGetList);
```

Use Json2C# to create the ClassName you need to have to be able to deserialize straight into an object.

You can use object.**__**  to call upon any of the results: example with your code:

object.list.(93817(you will have to cast this with a JsonProperty, because c# doesn't allow methods with solely numbers)).item_id = 93817

cleaner : object.list.thenameyougavethemethod.item_id

Good luck, if you have more questions, just add comments

EDIT : I parsed the json string and added JsonProperties to your specific Json String; 
Just download the NewtonSoft .dll & don't forget to add a reference to your project ...

```
public class id93817
{
    public string item_id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string time_updated { get; set; }
    public string time_added { get; set; }
    public string tags { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
}

public class id935812
{
    public string item_id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string time_updated { get; set; }
    public string time_added { get; set; }
    public string tags { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
}

public class List
{
    [JsonProperty("93817")]
    public id93817 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("935812")]
    public id935812 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List list { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure about Json2C# but I tried "http://json2csharp.com/". do you mean this? It converts each number like "93817" to a class but I obviously cannot have so many classes. Any resolutions  for this?

Comment: C# is Csharp, so yes that is the correct site, making one class and putting all the other public classes in there works perfectly, don't think this will slow your pc/program down... its 2x nothing compared to other segments of code. Deserialising into a class containing all the other classes will yield you an object with every parameter containing your Json String 

Don't forget that paramaters which are solely numbers CANNOT be a class in c#, hence they will be called _invalid_95783 or something .. rename them into something of your preference and add a [JsonProperty] tag

Comment: Example :                                                    [JsonProperty("93817")]                                                               public string item93817{ get; set; }

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is that the numbers are dynamically generated, which is also generated from a web server. So I really don't know what the next number is. Therefore, the hard coding is impossible.  Is there a way to abstract(or ignore) these numbers and get the information from JSON?

Comment: So far as I know, the only way to do that is by casting it into an Anonymous object... the results of these might vary .. 
I think the best solution for you is asking the creators of the web service to add a single letter in front of all those random generated numbers, this will let you create an object with valid parameters.
You can also do it the long way and work with Tokens .. you should best read up about these on the NewtonSoft website. Good luck!

Comment: Using Dictionary type and the the issue is resolved. See my own reply for more info. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to Json.NET for deserializing the object. It is less error prone and fragile (and yes, it's open source and works on the phone)>

Comment: Tried Json.NET but failed to map the classes. I don't know how to deal with the numbers like "93817" and "935812".They are dynamically generated so I can't hard code them to classnames. Any ideas about handle this?

Comment: Use JSON.NET's LINQ based code. It will allow you to parse it while walking through it (instead of creating a class to serialize it into). The numeric values you're getting are probably instance numbers so you  can skip/ignore them if you use that.

Answer (score 0):

The first item in the lists are incorrect. Your JSON shows "93817" and "935812" but those are not properties on your items. The first part of your JSON must be a property name. You're doing it right for "list" because it corresponds to the `List` property of `ResponseItem`. Change those numbers to "listArticle". I also second Shawn Wildermuth's suggestion for JSON.Net.

The JSON that is generated on the server should be serialized the same way that it is deserialized (ie: use the same framework to (de)serialize). If you are generating the JSON by hand, don't. You will have more problems than you need or want.

If you serialize the object, you should have the following:

```
{   "status":"1",
    "list":{
        "listArticle":{
            "item_id":"93817",         
            "url":"http://url.com",         
            "title":"Page Title",         
            "time_updated":"1245626956",                
            "time_added":"1245626956",                
            "tags":"comma,seperated,list",         
            "state":"0"                       
        },
        "listArticle":{
            "item_id":"935812",         
            "url":"http://google.com",        
            "title":"Google",         
            "time_updated":"1245626956",       
            "time_added":"1245626956",      
            "tags":"comma,seperated,list",         
            "state":"1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I failed to map it based on my understanding of your comments. What should I do with  "93817" and "935812" ? They are dynamically generated so I can't hard code them to classnames. Any ideas about handle this?

Comment: Using Dictionary type and the the issue is resolved. See my own reply for more info. Thanks, anyway.